# How to fix slow website loading in angular caused by webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, node-modules

Website is loading too slow it takes 5 seconds to load it. I have checked it in performance tab of chromes DevTools and it showed that the problem has something to do with Webpack. Does anyone know how to fix it? 
P.S I didn't import unnecessary modules or wrote bad code and also Network tab shows that DomContentLoaded 5 seconds.

[performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy6H4.png)

[performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFb4X.png)

[performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PULIK.png)

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) on how to deploy your application

Comment: steps you can take are , use lazy-loading of modules , `ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer `

Comment: package.json file may i got screen shot of that or use  npm run serve

Comment: alos use `ng serve --aot`  for serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the ahead of time (AOT) compilation. While you're developing, try "ng serve --aot", production builds usually are AOT with default configuration

Comment: But it definitifely should have changed something, especially something like in this screenshot shouldn't be visible any more? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFb4X.png

Comment: Hey sorry I checked it again now it works ( apparently i did something wrong that time). Thanks:).